# How to implement an interface with concrete type parameters in Clojure?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, clojure

I am trying to use AWS Lambda from Clojure. This is the Java code that works:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Dbmgmt implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object in, Context ctx) {
        System.out.println("ok");
        ctx.getLogger().log("ok");
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

This is the Clojure code that does not work.

```
(defn -handleRequest [this in ctx]
  (reify RequestHandler
    (handleRequest [this in ctx] "ok")))
```

Using Javap on both classes:

Java:

```
Compiled from "Dbmgmt.java"
public class com.streambright.Dbmgmt implements com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> {
  public com.streambright.Dbmgmt();
  public java.lang.String handleRequest(java.lang.Object, com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context);
  public java.lang.Object handleRequest(java.lang.Object, com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context);
}
```

Clojure:

```
public class dbmgmt implements com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler {
  public static {};
  public dbmgmt();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public int hashCode();
  public java.lang.Object clone();
  public java.lang.Object handleRequest(java.lang.Object, com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

I was wondering what is the best way to implement an interface with concrete return type. With the current code AWS complains:

```
"errorMessage": "Class dbmgmt does not implement RequestHandler with concrete type parameters"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could get to solve this is the following:

```
(ns dbmgmt
  (:gen-class
    :implements [com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler]
    :methods [[handleRequest [Object com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context] String]]))
```

This generates the following class:

```
public class dbmgmt implements com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler {
  public static {};
  public dbmgmt();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public int hashCode();
  public java.lang.Object clone();
  public java.lang.Object handleRequest(java.lang.Object, com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context);
  public java.lang.String handleRequest(java.lang.Object, com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context);
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

However it still does not have RequestHandler that the Java version has. I believe it is not possible to implement this purely in Clojure as of now.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you do not implement the `handleRequest` method with return class `String`, only `Object`.  You can give it as a "type hint" to the method name:

```
(reify RequestHandler
  (^String handleRequest [this ^Object in ^Context ctx] "ok")))
```

(*EDIT*: revert edit, but add complete type hints, which seem to be required.)

Comment: Yes I was thinking about the same, unfortuntaly it did not work.